# swapStyleSheet in extjs using absolute path

Tags: extjs4

I am using multiple namespaces in my application and I would like to be able to use the same stylesheet in different parts of my app. When I load an extjs app in my root route ("/"), and I call the following method

```
Ext.util.CSS.swapStyleSheet("theme","/ext-4.1.1a/resources/css/ext-all-access.css");
```

, extjs appropriately will load the stylesheet at:

```
/ext-4.1.1a/resources/css/ext-all-access.css
```

However if I am loading my extjs app from inside a view at "/admin/pages", extjs will attempt to load my stylesheet at

```
/admin/ext-4.1.1a/resources/css/ext-all-access.css
```

Any idea how to get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try passing the full url, like:

```
Ext.util.CSS.swapStyleSheet("theme", window.location.origin + "/ext-4.1.1a/resources/css/ext-all-access.css");
```